# How to create objects inside Mongodb map

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, pymongo

I have a document that looks like this, I am using mongo $map to project fields inside the table and rename the key. I can't use `$unwind` due to some internal complexity.

```
{
"Table":[
    {"Lookup":{
        "CreatedBy":{
            "id": "User001",
            "Name":"UserName"
         }

        }
     }]
}
```

The output I am expecting looks something like this

```
{
"Table":[
    {"Lookup":{
        "CreatedBy":"UserName"
        }
     }]
}
```

I am trying to achieve it with mongo $map but it is not supported

```
db.getCollection('TableDoc').aggregate([
        {
        "$project": {
            "Table": {
                "$map": {
                    "input": "$Table",
                    "in": {
                      "Lookup.CreatedAt": "$$this.Lookup.CreatedAt.Name",
                    }
                }               
             }
         }
        }
])
```

Is there any other way to achieve this without using $unwind

Comment: Sorry but your abstracted structure here is not valid. Instead of showing an abstract, just show us a real document ( with values replaced if you really must ) and what you expect it to look like. You cannot have "key names" directly within an array, and only inside an "object".

Comment: @NeilLunn Sorry that was a mistake. The real document looks exactly like that. A document with list of nested obejcts

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is supported with [`$map`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/), but just not using "dotted field paths". Instead you use "absolute" object structures:

```
collection.aggregate([
  { "$addFields": {
    "Table": {
      "$map": {
        "input": "$Table",
        "in": {
          "Lookup": {
            "CreatedBy": "$$this.Lookup.CreatedBy.Name"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }}
])
```

Alternately if you have lots of fields in the objects you can use [`$mergeObjects`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/mergeObjects/) where supported:

```
collection.aggregate([
  { "$addFields": {
    "Table": {
      "$map": {
        "input": "$Table",
        "in": {
          "$mergeObjects": [
            "$$this",
            { 
              "Lookup": {
                "CreatedBy": "$$this.Lookup.CreatedBy.Name"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }}
])
```

That makes more sense when an example shows more fields than your sample in the question does.

Comment: Thank you so much. Works like a charm.